# Why won't my Razor, ASP.NET, C# HTTPRequests return the body of the Response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, recaptcha

My ultimate goal is to get reCaptcha to work in my Razor app, but I am stuck. I've gotten to the point where I can get Response Headers back, but have no idea how to get the actual JSON response body back.  Let me know if you need more info.

In Startup.cs ----------------------------------

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
```

In Models > Voter.cs ----------------------------------

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace rethianIdeas.Models
{
    public class Voter
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data is required.")]
        public string reCaptchaPost { get; set; }

        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Vote2.cshtml.cs ----------------------------------

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using rethianIdeas.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace rethianIdeas.Pages.Ideas
{
    public class Vote2Model : PageModel
    {

        [BindProperty]
        public Voter reCaptchaTest { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(Name = "g-recaptcha-response")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "No One Beats Reacaptcha!")]
        public string reCaptchaG { get; set; }


        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            if (reCaptchaTest == null)
            {
                reCaptchaTest = new Voter();
            }

            return Page();
        }

        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public Vote2Model(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcUFJUUAAAAADvuNOTGONNAGETITiFgNNG0sxBg&response=";

                string Response_String = reCaptchaG;

                string GetRequest = URL + Response_String;

                var reCaptchaRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, GetRequest);
               reCaptchaRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");


                var Client = _clientFactory.CreateClient().SendAsync(reCaptchaRequest);

                reCaptchaTest.Result = Client.Result.ToString();

            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

In Vote2.cshtml ----------------------------------

```
@page
@model rethianIdeas.Pages.Ideas.Vote2Model

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="@Model.reCaptchaTest.reCaptchaPost"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.reCaptchaTest.reCaptchaPost" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.reCaptchaTest.reCaptchaPost"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcUFJUUAAAAANOTGETTINGIT0SYj77GZHEhz73p0Q6_m"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    <div><label>Result: @Model.reCaptchaTest.Result</label></div>
</form>
```

Returns  ----------------------------------

```
Result: StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers: { Date: Fri, 08 Mar 2019 06:02:16 GMT Cache-Control: max-age=0, private X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39" Accept-Ranges: none Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: Fri, 08 Mar 2019 06:02:16 GMT }
```

I simply cannot figure out how to get the body of the request out of this thing. Please Help.

Comment: So, my original post had a MASSIVE problem. I wasn't actually replacing the response= part of the URL with the user's reCaptcha response. I fixed the problem but still don't know how to get the body of the JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an asynchronous method but not waiting (`await`) for it to return.

This should get you going down the right path.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=***&response=";

        string Response_String = reCaptchaG;

        string GetRequest = URL + Response_String;

        var reCaptchaRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, GetRequest);
        reCaptchaRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.SendAsync(reCaptchaRequest);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            reCaptchaTest.Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            // Errors, do something...
        }
    }

    return Page();
}
```

You can reference the ASP.NET Core [Http.Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) docs for more info. Also, [here](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/may/using-google-recaptcha-v2-in-aspnet-core-web-application/) is a blog post covering using ASP.NET Core and reCaptcha.

Comment: Dear God that worked! You have no idea how many hours I spent on this. Thanks so much. There was one minor change though. had to also add an await to this line:
    {
        reCaptchaTest.Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }